# Music App forgets what it was doing

Tags: music, playlist, resume

When resuming music playback after a break (10 minutes, few days, another app playing content) it ignores whatever playlist, album, artist or other refinement was placed on the music list and simply plays at random from the entire library.

Is there a way to set it so that resuming playback will resume in the playlist it was last playing?  If the music app is opened directly, it remembers where it was, so why not when using the play button on the lock screen, or when attaching a Bluetooth device, or plugging it into a speaker?

For example, I was playing Christmas music on a speaker system at home.  I unplugged the iPod 5, went out to my car, automatically paired to the Apple compatible in dash Bluetooth and resumed playback.  It picked up where it left off in the same song it was playing, but showed the number of songs in the entire library (not the playlist) and shuffled to another song in the library after the current song, not in the previously loaded playlist.  I had to unlock the iPod, open the music app, return to the main screen, select playlists, select the desired playlist, select a song and then play.  That's a lot of steps to resume playing a music playlist on a music playing device (especially while driving).

For another example, I was listening to a playlist using the built in speaker of my iPod 5.  I took a phone call, so I swiped up and pressed pause.  While on the phone, I used another app, then set the iPod down.  After the phone call, I pressed the home button and simply pressed play on the lock screen.  Same as above, it resumed the song it was on, but then randomly went off to another song not in the playlist.  Upon unlocking and loading the music app, it wasn't in playlist anymore, but simply shuffling the entire library.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is somewhat of a missing feature from all the various music players I can find.  It has been discussed in several other threads over the years (and through many versions of iOS) and no one seems to have a solution:

https://discussions.apple.com/message/23287490#23287490
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4385600?start=0&tstart=0

:(